# Matrix and other arrays : Converter to Latex/MathJAX?

Tags: support, mathjax

For matrices, system of equations, and other arrays, is there something akin to http://truben.no/latex/table/? Latex/MathJAX can smart the eyes.

Comment: You mean a WYSIWYG editor ?

Comment: Maybe this helpfull: http://jsfiddle.net/DMd4j/4/

Comment: @Kasper: Thank you. I'm interested in something like that link where I only have to input, with no TEX, entries and then choose the size, style, etc... of matrix and to receive the latex as output. I tried your second comment but it does requier input of TEX?